# How can i convert date in specific format in javascript? Without using any library

Tags: javascript

```js
var options = {timeZone:'Asia/Tokyo'};
var date  = new Date(1502722800000);
date.toString('YYYYMMDD HH:MM');
console.log('formatted date '+date);
```

o/p - Mon Aug 14 2017 20:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

But I  want o/p in this date format('YYYYMMDD HH:MM') as 20170814 17:30

Comment: [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) does not accept any arguments. I'd recommend looking into [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: You'll have to extract year, month, dates etc. manually and construct the desired date string or you can use moment.js as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was about a solution in JavaScript for a specific format, so without any additional libraries, a straight forward answer would be (in the style of the shim for [Date.toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)):

```
function pad(number) {
    if (number < 10) {
        return '0' + number;
    }
    return number;
}

function toMyDateFormat(s) {
    return this.getUTCFullYear() +
        pad(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) +
        pad(this.getUTCDate()) +
        ' ' + pad(this.getUTCHours()) +
        ':' + pad(this.getUTCMinutes());
};
```

Just for curiosity, this is my shortest solution without any library:

```
function toMyDateFormat(d) {
    return d.toISOString().replace(/-/g,'').replace('T', ' ').substr(0,14);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SurisDziugas is right, with moment, you can just create and format your date like this `moment(1502722800000).format('YYYYMMDD HH:MM');`
I actually stopped using JS native `Date` object, `moment` offers better possibilities.

Comment: How can i use timezone?

Answer (score 0):

[`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) does not accept any arguments, and cannot be used like this. I would recommend using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

For example:

```js
var formatted = moment(1502722800000).format('YYYY/MM/DD h:mm');
console.log('formatted date '+formatted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you wish to work with timezones, you can also add [Moment Timezones](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Answer (score 0):

Without using any library, this can be your long solution.

```js
 function formatDate(date) {
        var month = '' + (date.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + date.getDate(),
            year = "" + date.getFullYear(),
            hour = "" + date.getHours(),
            min = "" + date.getMinutes();

        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
        if (hour.length < 2) hour = '0' + hour;
        if (min.length < 2) min = '0' + min;

        return year+"/" + month +"/"+ day + " " + hour + ":" + min;
    }
    var options = {
        timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo'
    };
    var date = new Date(1502722800000);
    console.log(formatDate(date));
```

I hope this helps

Comment: You can save few bytes by replacing `if` conditionals with `('0'+month).slice(-2)` and similar for hours, minutes, etc.